# Merge rows from two diff-structure tables into single one without loop?

Tags: loops, abap, internal-tables

I have *two internal tables* with a content: `itab1`, `itab2` and one *final table* `ftab`. I need to move the contents from `itab1` and `itab2` to `ftab` with corresponding values.

For example, move the first record of `itab1` to the corresponging first record of `ftab` and also the first record of `itab2` to the corresponding first record of `ftab` keeping all the values from both tables. Basically it means to *merge the contents* of the first records of both  tables and put it into the final table.

I can do it by using `ftab = CORRESPONDING #( itab1 )`, subsequent looping at `ftab`, reading `itab2` and filling the remaining columns.

I want to know - is there any way to do it without using loop?

Comment: I wonder why you ask to do differently something which works, but as you already know the `CORRESPONDING` [Constructor Operator](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_latest_index_htm/latest/en-US/index.htm?file=abenconstructor_expressions.htm), just learn the other ones (`VALUE`, `REDUCE`, `FILTER`, etc.), in which the loop is prefixed with the word `FOR` instead of `LOOP AT` (no revolution here).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually there is no possibility to merge as described 2 tables into a third one without looping. Using `CORRESPONDING` it is possible just to add second table's content after the content of the first one.

What is actually possible is to make the looping and filling the target table in one statemet using *iteration expression* `FOR` and *component operator* `CORRESPONDING`. Below I wrote an example code for this.

Data declarations:

```
  TYPES:
    BEGIN OF ty_itab1,
      matnr_1 TYPE mara-matnr,
      text_1  TYPE mara-zeinr,
      text_2  TYPE mara-ferth,
      text_3  TYPE mara-ferth,
    END OF ty_itab1,
    BEGIN OF ty_itab2,
      descr_1 TYPE mara-zeinr,
      descr_2 TYPE mara-ferth,
      descr_3 TYPE mara-ferth,
    END OF ty_itab2,
    BEGIN OF ty_ftab.
      INCLUDE TYPE ty_itab1.
      INCLUDE TYPE ty_itab2.
      TYPES: zfield TYPE mara-ferth,
    END OF ty_ftab,
    ty_t_itab1 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_itab1 WITH DEFAULT KEY,
    ty_t_itab2 TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_itab2 WITH DEFAULT KEY,
    ty_t_ftab  TYPE STANDARD TABLE OF ty_ftab  WITH DEFAULT KEY.
```

Fill in some sample data:

```
DATA(lt_itab1) = VALUE ty_t_itab1( 
( matnr_1 = '123MAT1' text_1 = 'Text 1' text_2 = 'Note 1' text_3 = 'Data 1' )
( matnr_1 = '123MAT2' text_1 = 'Text 2' text_2 = 'Note 2' text_3 = 'Data 2' )
( matnr_1 = '123MAT3' text_1 = 'Text 3' text_2 = 'Note 3' text_3 = 'Data 3' )
( matnr_1 = '123MAT4' text_1 = 'Text 4' text_2 = 'Note 4' text_3 = 'Data 4' ) ).

DATA(lt_itab2) = VALUE ty_t_itab2( 
( descr_1 = 'Description 1' descr_2 = 'Info 1' descr_3 = 'Map 1')
( descr_1 = 'Description 2' descr_2 = 'Info 2'  descr_3 = 'Map 2')
( descr_1 = 'Description 3' descr_2 = 'Info 3'  descr_3 = 'Map 3' ) ).
```

Build a target table `lt_ftab` which is a merge of the two above:

```
  DATA(lt_ftab) = VALUE ty_t_ftab(
    FOR ls_itab1 IN lt_itab1 INDEX INTO lv_index
      LET ls_ftab = VALUE ty_ftab(
        descr_1 = VALUE #( lt_itab2[ lv_index ]-descr_1 OPTIONAL )
        descr_2 = VALUE #( lt_itab2[ lv_index ]-descr_2 OPTIONAL )
        zfield  = VALUE #( lt_itab2[ lv_index ]-descr_3 OPTIONAL )
      )
      IN ( CORRESPONDING #( BASE ( ls_ftab ) ls_itab1 ) ) ).
```

If you use this statement instead:

```
DATA(lt_ftab) = CORRESPONDING ty_t_ftab( BASE ( lt_itab1 ) lt_itab2 
                MAPPING zfield = descr_3 ).
```

the content of two tables will be just added together but not merged.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what i have used but just needed to know if there was a way, I guess there isn't.